# MySQL Event scheduling for a specific period of time everyday with an interval of 30 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL trading application which runs from 10:00AM till 6:00PM everyday. It has a chart that shows trading progress every 30 minutes starting from 10:00AM.

Can anyone please help me defining the ON SCHEDULE part of the MySQL event definition?

Just to clarify, first reading starts at 10:00AM, 2nd 10:30, 3rd 11:00 and so till the last reading at 6:00PM.

Comment: Not sure I got this. You want to have some external scheduler and do not now how to schedule every 30 minutes, bot 10:00AM-06:00PM only, right? If yes, which scheduler do you have (cron?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is check the time in the event itself. Something like this

```
CREATE EVENT your_event ON SCHEDULE 
       EVERY 30 MINUTE
       STARTS '2013-10-01 10:00:00'
    DO
      IF time(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between time('10:00:00') and time('18:00:00')
      then
            ....
      end if;
```

Comment: With this it will run more than 4 times. It will run every 30 minutes between 10 - 18.

Comment: Yes the event will be triggered every 30 minutes. But it will not **do** anything in the time outside the specified one.

Comment: As i understood it needed to be execute 4 times. At 10, 10:30, 11 and 18. not every 30 minutes?

Comment: From the question: *every 30 minutes starting from 10:00AM*

Comment: Juergen d, don't see any better way. Wish events could've been nested. Thanks for the effort.